# How can I get all values from my array in a loop in php?

Tags: php, array

I've following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 585
            [1] => 596
        )

)
```

Now I want to print all values (585 & 595 .....) row for row in a loop. I need this an a loop because I need to to something with every value before the output. The problem is that I don't get all values, just one:

```
foreach ( $entries as $entry ) {
    echo $entry[ 0 ];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your entries are nested, then you need to run another loop inside your first loop, but I'd test it to see if it's an array and that it's not empty.

```
foreach ( $entries as $entry ) {
    if ( is_array( $entry ) && !empty( $entry ) ) {
        foreach ( $entry as $sub_entry ) {
           echo $sub_entry;
        }
    }
}
```

I know there are other ways of being more complete about this, but this is the simplest answer I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: You missed the ) at the end of the if :) and thanks a lot! Works great :D

Comment: Haha, I usually miss something in my code :)
I fixed it.

Comment: If you'd be so kind as to mark it as correct, I'd appreciate it. Otherwise, if you're waiting for other answers, I understand.

Comment: I've tried but I need to wait some minutes :) Be patient ;)

Comment: "You can accept an answer in 47 seconds"

Comment: Haha, I didn't know that was a thing.  Thanks a lot!!